# i have a .ps1 file which fetch folder content from the folder.how to run that .ps1 file from jmeter so i can do performance testing?

Tags: powershell, jmeter, performance-testing

I have a `.ps1` file which fetch folder content from the folder. How to run that `.ps1` file from `jmeter` so I can do performance testing?

```
PS C:\Users\######> D:\KANHA_####\niii1.ps1
```

Comment: Please update the question with what steps you have tried so far.

Comment: suppose i have a powershell script which read file inside my folder.i want to run that powershell script in jmeter so that i will judge how much time it will take to read each each file.

my powershell script :- PS C:\Users\jsjs> D:\KANHA_kww\test1.ps1

Answer (score 0):

1. Add [OS Process Sampler](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#OS_Process_Sampler) to your Test Plan
2. Configure it as follows:

   - Command: `C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe`
   - Argument 1: `-File`
   - Argument 2: `C:\Users######> D:\KANHA_####\niii1.ps1`

That's it, when you run the test JMeter will execute the script and you will be able to see the output using i.e. [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener.

More information: [How to Run External Commands and Programs Locally and Remotely from JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter) article for more information.

P.S. You might need to [amend execution policy settings](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee176961.aspx)